# Bot Framework updating Teams activity with empty content

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am experimenting some strange behaviour between a bot and MS Teams.

Basically the bot sends me an Adaptive Card and when I interact again the bot will update that last message holding that card with "I got updated!"

Inside MS Teams (both Windows desktop and web) the messages gets updated indicating "Updated" but with an empty content. This content is not filled until I change conversations.

I can't tell if this is an expected behaviour or if I'm making some kind of mistake, this is a simplified example of the code:

```json
"dependencies": {
        "adaptivecards": "^2.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.0",
        "botbuilder": "~4.8.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "restify": "~8.4.0",
        (...)
}
```

```js
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({...});

adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

const myBot = new EchoBot();

static processActivity(req, res) {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async context => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
    }
```

```js
class EchoBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onMessage(async (context) => {
            await doSomething(context);
        });
    }
}
```

```js
someCardContent = {...};
lastCardId = undefinded;

async function doSomething(turnContext) {
    if (!lastCardId) {
        { lastCardId } = await turnContext.sendActivity(MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.adaptiveCard(someCardContent)));
    } else {
        const newActivity = MessageFactory.text('I got updated!');
        newActivity.id = lastCardId;
        lastCardId = undefinded;
        await turnContext.updateActivity(newActivity)
    }
}
```

Order as seen in Teams:

- 1 I interact with the bot (greeting it)
- 2 The bot sends me a card:
  [image: Original message]
- 3 I interact again (pressing the button), the card gets updated ("Actualizado" = "Updated"):
  [image: Updated Message]
- 4 I switch conversations and come back to the bot's chat
  [image: Updated Message after conversation switch]

Comment: Is the content an image of some sort? There are some issues with Adaptive Cards not rendering images properly right away

Comment: No images, only text, input text's or buttons

Comment: Could you please share your manifest, so that we can test and revert back to you.

Comment: Sorry, can't share it :( btw, it's for a private company domain.

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/3822

Comment: Replacing the adaptive card with a new adaptive card doesn't have the same refresh issue, it is when you replace the adaptive card with a text message this happens.

Comment: @Fradantim - could you please confirm if you are facing same issue when you update with new adaptive card? Could you please try [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-sequential-flow-adaptive-cards/nodejs) and let me know if it's working for you?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT updating with an adaptive card does indeed work. I will try the example as soon as I can, does it consists of updating previously sent cards?

Comment: Yes. It shows sample for User Specific Views & Up to date cards. Take a look at docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/overview?tabs=mobile

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thanks for the info! I was looking for this specific case (my question), since the text message would show a static content using less visual space.